# Producer/consumer system using database (MySql), is this feasible?

Tags: mysql, database, system, consumer, producer

I need to use *something* to coordinate my system with several consumers/producers each running on different machines with different operating systems. I have been researching on using MySql to do this, but it seems ridiculously difficult.

My requirements are simple: I want to be able to add or remove consumers/producers at any time and thus they should not depend on each other at all. Naturally a database would separate the two nicely.

I have been looking at Q4M message queuing plugin for MySql but it seems complicated to use.

I really need some input on how to construct my system best possible.

Comment: Are you asking about the architecture?  Message Queues are the standard solution.  Are you asking about your technical problems building Q4M?  Please focus your question either on architecture in general or Q4M in particular.  It's hard to answer both.

Comment: This question is about the architecture. I will post another one specific on Q4M compilation.

Comment: If you actually are asking about the architecture, can you please edit your question to focus on the architecture?  The distraction of the Q4M problem makes it hard for people to figure your question out and offer sensible help.  Please delete the distracting stuff and focus on your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to use something to coordinate
>   my system with several
>   consumers/producers each running on
>   different machines with different
>   operating systems

That's a message queue.  Do not pursue other alternatives.  Everything else (i.e., using a database with insert and deletes) is dreadfully slow and cumbersome.

Building a large, slow message queue with a database often turns out badly in practice because (1) databases are slow, (2) databases are huge and complex, (3) you have locking and contention issues that make each transaction potentially slow, (4) it's a lot more overhead than the problem deserves.

There are numerous message queue solutions.

If you can't make Q4M work, you should move on to another.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview

http://qpid.apache.org/

http://code.google.com/p/httpsqs/

Comment: I see. Thanks for the links. I guess I will use a message queue solution then. MSMQ sounds like a nice solution (for .net).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually (fairly) complicated to build such system. (I say fairly, because it's of course doable).

If you have multiple producer and *one* consumer, it's easy. All producer write concurrently, and the single consumer read data as soon as they are visible (committed).

But if you want scalability with *several* consumer, you will need to create a locking scheme that is not trivial. (You must ensure that no row gets dispatched to two consumers. This is not easy to achieve with database transactions and locks. Naive solutions lead to the serialization of all message delivery, like you had only one consumer, which we don't want.).

I would suggest to use a built-in solution. You can also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096734/why-choosing-jms-for-asynchronous-solution-why-is-it-better-than-a-simple-entit/2096760#2096760) about a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's feasible without third-party software.

My first design would look like this:

- The producer writes data to the database
- To guarantee consistency it has to use transactions
- The consumer process the data (read and delete) also using transactions.

Because of the transactions requirement InnoDB is the logical choice of the storage engine. Also you have to carefully choose the isolation level. My first guess is "serializable" to avoid phantom reads, but perhaps a weaker level also is possible.

If performance and scalability is an issue, you should consider using a "real" messaging solution. Rolling out your one will most likely lead to performance and/or scalability issues.

Answer (score 0):

It depends situations.

In my case, the only one producer make thousands message per day, and several consumers consume these messages in the following 24 hours, which each one take several minites to finish. So, I think the mysql would meet my requirement, and I can use the transactions to ensure the consistency between consumers.

Hope it will help.