# What is Java Message Service (JMS) for?

Tags: java, jms

I am currently evaluating JMS and I don't get what I could use it for.

Currently, I believe this would be a Usecase: I want to create a SalesInvoice PDF and print it when an SalesOrder leaves the Warehouse, so during the Delivery transaction I could send a transactional print request which just begins when the SalesOrder transaction completes successfully.

Now I found out most JMS products are standalone server.

- Why would a need a Standalone Server for Message Processing, vs. e.g. some simple inproc processing with Quartz scheduler?
- How does it interact with my application?
- Isn't it much too slow?
- What are Usecases you already implemented successfully?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035949/real-world-use-of-jms-message-queues

Comment: If you don't have a use for it, then it would seem your evaluation is complete. ;)

Comment: TO understand the concepts associated with messaging and what patterns JMS can help with, all you need is: http://www.eaipatterns.com/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

JMS is an amazingly useful system, but not for every purpose.

It's essentially a high-level framework for sending messages between nodes, with options for discovery, robustness, etc.

One useful use case is when you want a client and a server to talk to one another, but without the client actually having the server's address (E.g., you may have more than one server). The client only needs to know the broker and the queue/topic name, and the server can connect as well.

JMS also adds robustness. For instance, you can configure it so that if the server dies while the client sends messages or the other way around, you can still send messages from the client or poll messages from the server. If you ever tried implementing this directly with sockets - it's a nightmare.

The scenario you describe sounds like a classic J2EE problem, why are you not using a J2EE framework? JMS is often used inside J2EE for communications, but you got all the other benefits.

Comment: +1: I may misunderstand, but i thought JMS was part of J2EE and made to make J2EE components communicate...this is not the case ?

Comment: They don't have to be J2EE components.  Any Java components can use JMS.

Comment: No, you can use JMS independently of J2EE beans. I've done that often enough and it's super easy. However, your problem sounds like it could benefit from EJBs, in which case JMS is behind the scenes.

Comment: Most applications use Message Driven Beans to consume messages (to benefit from clustering and load balancing) but a simple Java class can be a consumer. And by the way, J2EE doesn't exist anymore since 2005, it's Java EE for more than 5 years now :)

Comment: I thought that application servers use JMS for MDBs. 
Good point about J2EE; I haven't touched that stuff in way longer than 5 years :)

Comment: @Uri: same thing for me, sorry for the Java EE purists...:-)

Answer (score 18):

> What ist Java Message Service (JMS) for

JMS is **a messaging standard** that allows Java EE applications to create, send, receive, and consume messages in a loosely coupled, reliable, and asynchronous way. I'd suggest to read the [Java Message Service API Overview](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/overview.html) for more details.

> Why would a need a Standalone Server for Message Processing, vs. e.g. some simple inproc processing with Quartz scheduler?

Sure, in your case, Quartz is an option. But what if the invoice system is a remote system? What if you don't want to wait for the answer? What if the remote system is down when you want to communicate with it? What if the network is not always available? This is where JMS comes in. JMS allows to send a message guaranteed to be delivered and to consume it in a transactional way (sending or consuming a message can be part of a global transaction).

> How does it interact with my application?

JMS supports two communication modes: point-to-point and publish/subscribe (if this answers the question).

> Isn't it much too slow?

The MOMs I've been working with were blazing fast.

> What are Usecases you already implemented successfully?

Used in system such as a reservation application, a banking back-office (processing market data), or more simply to send emails.

#### See also

- [EJB Message-Driven Beans](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/ejb3_ch13/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

> Why would a need a Standalone Server
>   for Message Processing, vs. e.g. some
>   simple inproc processing with Quartz
>   scheduler?

The strength of JMS lies in the fact that you can have **multiple producers and multiple consumers** for the same queue, and the JMS broker manages the load.

If you have multiple producers but a **single consumer**, you can use other approaches as well, such as a quartz scheduler and a database table. But as soon as you have multiple consumer, the locking scheme become very hard to design; better go for already approved messaging solution. See these other answers from me for a few more details:  [Why choosing JMS for asynchronous solution ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096734/why-choosing-jms-for-asynchronous-solution-why-is-it-better-than-a-simple-entit) and [Producer/consumer system using database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449172/producer-consumer-system-using-database-mysql-is-this-feasible)

The other points are just too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

I've used it on a number of projects.  It can help with scalability, decoupling of services, high availability.  Here's a description of how I used it on a project several years ago:

http://coders-log.blogspot.com/2008/12/favorite-projects-series-installment-2.html

The description explains what JMS brought to the table for this particular project, but other projects will use messaging systems for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/package-summary.html):

> The Java Message Service (JMS) API provides a common way for Java programs to create, send, receive and read an enterprise messaging system's messages.

In other words, and contrary to every other answer here, JMS is nothing more than an ***API,*** which *wraps* access to third-party Message Brokers, via 'JMS Providers' implemented by the vendor. Those *Message Brokers*, such as IBM MQ and dozens of others, have the features of reliability, asynchronicity, etc. that have been mentioned in other answers. JMS itself provides exactly none of them. It is to Message Brokers what JDBC is to SQL databases, or JNDI is to LDAP servers (among other things).

Comment: Okey, take my vote instead. But in fact the answer sounds a bit pedantic.

Comment: @Daniel I don't know what that means, unless it merely means 'correct', or is a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

JMS is a [message-oriented middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Oriented_Middleware).

> - Why would a need a Standalone Server for Message Processing, vs. e.g. some simple inproc processing with Quartz scheduler?

It depends on what other components you may have. I guess. But I don't know anything about Quartz

> - How does it interact with my application?

You send messages to the broker.

> - Isn't it much too slow?

Compare to what ?

> - What are Usecases you already implemented successfully?

I've used JMS to implement a SIP application server, to communicate between the various components.

Answer (score 1):

Messaging is usually used to interconnect different systems and send requests/commands asynchronously. A common example is a bank client application requesting an approval for a transaction. The server is located in another bank's system. Both systems are connected in an Enterprise Service Bus. The request goes into the messaging bus, which instantly acknowledges the reception of the message. The client can go on with processing. Whenever the server system becomes available, the bus forwards the message to it. Of course there needs to be a second path, for the server to inform the client that the transaction executed successfully or failed. This again can be implemented with JMS.

Please note that the two systems need not to implement JMS. One can use JMS and the other one MSMQ. The bus will take care of the interconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very good explanation of JMS with an example.

That is a simple chat application with JMS queues are used to communicate messages between users and messages stay in the queue if the receiver is offline.

In this example implementation they have used

- XSD to generate domain classes.
- Eclipse EE as IDE.
- JBoss as web/application server.
- HTML/JavaScript/JQuery for UI.
- Servlet as controller.
- MySQL as DB.

The JBoss configuration step for queue is explained nicely
Its available at http://coder2design.com/messaging-service/

Even the downloadable code is also available there.